# Facebook php sdk v. 4x and canvas application and loggin in

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm trying to make a Facebook canvas application, and I'm having troubles with users logging in. All the answers I found on Stackoverflow were outdated, or didn't work.

What I have now is:

(index page)
    Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($this->app_id, $this->app_secret);

```
        $helper = new Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();

        try {

          $this->fb_session = $helper->getSession();

        } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        }
        if(!empty($this->fb_session)){
        //we have a session, this works
        }

       if(!$this->fb_session){//no session, let's get one
        $helper = new           Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('https://apps.facebook.com/'.$app_id.'/');
        $data['login_url'] = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('email','user_friends'));
        $this->render('homepage/redirect',$data);//this just renders a page described below, giving it a $login_url variable
        return;
    }
```

And homepage/redirect looks like this:

```
<script>
    top.location.href = '<?=$login_url?>';
</script>
```

This all works when we enter this particular page, but there is no session on other pages, how can I keep it active on all the pages?

Comment: Store the session in $_SESSION and check it on other pages

Comment: I already handled it (using $_SESSION as you suggested), but thanks anyway!